# Считывание из потока в конструктор и создание объекта при добавлениии

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Friend{
Friend(const int &must_authority,const int &add_authority): must_authority(must_authority), add_authority(add_authority){}
    int must_authority, add_authority;
};
int main(){
    int nFriends, authority;
    std::cin >> nFriends >> authority;
    std::vector<Friend> v_friend;

    for (int i = 0; i < nFriends; i++){  
        v_friend.push_back(???);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

1) Как считать из потока в конструктор? 
Аля:

```
Friend new_friend(след_число, след_число);
```

2) Можно ли создавать объект во время добавления?

```
v_friend.push_back(Friend(1, 1) );
```

или в таком случаи лучше писать так:

```
std::vector<Friend*> v_friend;  
v_friend.push_back(new Friend(1,1) );
```

Answer (score 2):

По поводу первого: в C/C++ порядок вычисления аргументов функции не определен Стандартом, так что то, что попадет на какую позицию - тайна богов, на временных переменных лучше не экономить, оберегает от UB, да и читается лучше.

```
Friend new_friend( первый_вызов(), второй_вызов() );
                        ?             ?
Friend new_friend( второй_вызов(), первый_вызов() );
```

По поводу второго: в этом случае

```
v_friend.push_back(Friend(1, 1) );
```

создается временный анонимный объект, потом он копируется в вектор, затем временный объект уничтожается. Если тип копировать нельзя по тем или иным причинам (конструктор копии, оператор присваивания приватные или deleted), то нужно совать туда указатели, как во втором варианте.

Comment: for (int must_authority, add_authority, i = 0; i < nFriends; i++){   
      std::cin >> must_authority >> add_authority;
      v_friend.push_back(Friend(must_authority, add_authority) );
     Только так?

Comment: @Aru
Можно обернуть ввод в функтор, который передавать аргументом в конструктор. Но,имо,проще и читабельней просто обернуть ввод в простую функцию, принимающую ссылку на поток, из которого брать значения.

    inline
Friend getFriendFromIStream( std::istream &stream )
{
    int must_authority = 0;
    int add_authority = 0;
    stream >> must_authority;
    stream >> add_authority;
    // Проверка аргументов на корректность
    return Friend(must_authority, add_authority);
}

// Заполнение вектора
for (i = 0; i < nFriends; i++)
{ 
    v_friend.push_back( getFriendFromIStream( std::cin ) );
}

Comment: @Aru


    inline
    Friend getFriendFromIStream( std::istream &stream )
    {
        int must_authority = 0;
        int add_authority = 0;
        stream >> must_authority;
        stream >> add_authority;
        // Проверка аргументов на корректность
        return Friend(must_authority, add_authority);
    }
    
    // Заполнение вектора
    for (i = 0; i < nFriends; i++)
    { 
        v_friend.push_back( getFriendFromIStream( std::cin ) );
    }

Answer (score 2):

Раз уж мы про C++11 говорим, то лучше писать вот так:

```
std::vector<Friend> v_friend;
v_friend.emplace_back(1, 1);
```

Метод emplace_back сам передаст аргументы конструктору Friend.